# VisualStudioCode. SFDX: Authorize an Org. error

Tags: visualstudiocode

In Visual Studio Code.
SFDX: Authorize an Org.
This error displayed.
"ERROR: We can’t query your org. Make sure that you’re connected to this org and have permissions to view the object and fields."
But connect user profile is custom Administrator.
Why the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try reconnecting org again or check if the ALIAS set correctly.